# How to avoid postback on a Image button click in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

my code for the button is

```
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" CommandName="Edit"
                                    ImageUrl="~/images/edit.png" ShowHeader="True" CausesValidation="false"/>
```

Comment: Maybe don't use Image Button control? You can use plain image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple HTML control instead of an ASP.NET Web Control.
If you can't, use Javascript in the OnClick Event

Use javascript - using the onclick client event

```
    <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" CommandName="Edit" onClick="return false;"                                    
ImageUrl="~/images/edit.png" ShowHeader="True" 
                                        CausesValidation="false"
                                        />
```

Comment: not getting it done when i tried to use img tag it displays an error message that you can not nest img tag in <column>.

Comment: So, please edit you request and post more code about the markup that "wrap" your ButtonField.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <img src="~/images/edit.png" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
```